# How to set up Apache 2 to serve only subdirectories

Tags: apache-2.2

I have 3 sites which need to be hosted on a web server (apache2 from repo running on Ubuntu 12.04). They are each in their own subdirectory within `/var/www/`

I would like apache to serve files from the relevant directories only if the directory name is given in the URL, but *not* serve the `/var/www/` directory itself.

E.g: `http://1.2.3.4/site1/` should work and serve the index from `/var/www/site1/index.html`, but `http://1.2.3.4/` should not serve anything.

Currently, I can't get the url to point to the directory. Either I can get `http://1.2.3.4/` to serve everything within `/var/www/` (including `/var/www/site2/secretstuff/`), or I can get the root `http://1.2.3.4/` to serve one of the subdirectories (`/var/www/site1/`). This is unacceptable site 1 needs Indexes enabled but the others must not.

I just want to make site1's config only respond to requests of the form `http://1.2.3.4/site1/*` and not handle requests of the form `http://1.2.3.4/`

I do not have a domain name set up so I can't use subdomains.

Answer (score 3):

Just go with the easy fix: put a blank `index.html` in `/var/www`:

```
touch /var/www/index.html
```

Going to the top level will then just result in a blank page.

Comment: Updated question with reasons why that doesn't work

Comment: I don't see anything in your question that would cause this to not work.

Comment: I was worried I wasn't clear enough. Essentially when I do what you say, it serves all the files from all the sites. I need some of the sites to only serve specific files (actually they're django+relevant static files). The django parts should not be served, but are in their respective /var/www/ directories

Comment: Aha, then you definitely should edit your question and provide a lot more details, especially about the django setup, your desired Apache configuration, etc.

Comment: All I want is to know how to make apache only respond to URLs which specify a subdirectory.

Comment: @LyndenShields Can you provide more examples about what requests you want to deny?  So far you've just specified the root path of `/`, which Michael's recommendation prevents serving an index page - do you have other URLs that present a problem?

Comment: So with this answer, `http://1.2.3.4./site2/secretstuff/` serves `/var/www/site2/secretstuff/`. This folder is full of secret stuff which should not be made public.

Comment: @LyndenShields So you're looking to allow access to `/site2/` and `/site2/page.html`, but block `/site2/secretstuff`?  Is that correct?   You want to allow resources only in subdirectories, but only one level deep in subdirectories?

Comment: It's pretty much the 'only in subdirectories' part that's important, I thought. As in, I already have site2 and site3's configs done correctly (django wsgi doing the private stuff + apache serving public static files), but site 1's config is either serving all 3 site's entire directories, or serving only its own but as the root url `http://1.2.3.4/` instead of `http:///1.2.3.4/site1`

Comment: I just want to make site1's config only respond to requests of the form `http://1.2.3.4/site1/*` and not handle requests of the form `http://1.2.3.4/`

Comment: @LyndenShields That's what this answer does. So far you have refused to explain why this doesn't work for you, which is quite frustrating for all of us. Please strongly consider actually doing so.

Comment: Please try not to get frustrated - this solution, as I have stated several times, DOES NOT prevent me from accessing `http://1.2.3.4/site2/secretstuff`, because site1's config serves it when it shouldn't, because as the question states, I don't know how to make site1's config not respond to the request `http://1.2.3.4/site2/*`. It shouldn't respond to anything other than URLs which specify the site1 subdirectory.

Comment: Does that clear it up for you at all?

Comment: @LyndenShields You _have_ to use virtual hosts for that sort of separation. There is no way around it. Go buy a domain name.

Comment: Do virtual hosts need to have domain names?

Comment: This does indeed seem to be the problem. I need to use Virtual Hosts for that kind of separation, but virtual hosts must be different domain/subdomains or different IPs, they can't be just different subdirectories?

Comment: Yes, but you can always use fake names, if this isn't going to be on the Internet. Otherwise... come on, a domain is less than $10 bucks.

Comment: OK - makes sense now. This question should probably be closed because it turns out I can't do exactly what I was trying to do?

Comment: It is internet facing - was just trying to not to have to get more domains set up.

Comment: Scrap that, I just managed to do it with an Alias instead of a DirectoryRoot in Site1's config.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what exactly you need, maybe you need to post httpd.conf?

Do you want the root URL to go to 404?  Maybe try

> RedirectMatch 404 ^/$

For the other part, this may help:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html#documentroot

Comment: http2.conf is empty as per normal install of apache2 from ubuntu repos

Answer (score 0):

I needed to replace the DirectoryRoot of Site 1's config with Alias /site1 /var/www/site1/

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the IPTABLES setting:

```
iptables -I INPUT -d <server IP> -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --to 70 \
--algo bm --string 'GET / HTTP' -j DROP
```

This won't kill requests for /file but anything requesting the root directly at / will not be allowed access.

Alternatively you could make a couple allow rules for the pages you want to have working and one to block the root:

```
iptables -I INPUT -d <server IP> -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --to 70 \
--algo bm --string 'GET /' -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -d <server IP> -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --to 70 \
--algo bm --string 'GET /site1' -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -d <server IP> -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --to 70 \
--algo bm --string 'GET /site2' -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -d <server IP> -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --to 70 \
--algo bm --string 'GET /site3' -j ACCEPT
```